# How to group VueJs elements

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Say I have a component (myComponent) :

```
<template>
   <v-container> <v-container>
</template>
```

And I want to reuse this multiple times, how do I group them, so it has no effect on the UI. For example :

```html
<myGroup v-if="myStore.property">
  <myComponent/>
  <myComponent/>
  <myComponent/>
  <myComponent/>
  <myComponent/>
</myGroup>
```

The reason for this is to run the check `v-if="myStore.property"` once, rather than on each component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `template` tag for grouping.

```
<template v-if="myStore.property">
  <myComponent/>
  <myComponent/>
  <myComponent/>
  <myComponent/>
  <myComponent/>
</template>
```

Comment: Correct, but not to confuse with top level `template` tag in which you can't use conditionals.

Comment: If you can't use template then you can simply use any other html tags. Like `div`.

Comment: Apologies, I must have missed the notification for this answer. Thank you